# Impossibilty to declare a number to an @input in angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I just started with angular and am just looking to declare an input. I am expecting a number and not a string in an object in an array and I can't get it, I don't understand what is wrong.  When I declare a number to the loveIts value (like that => loveIts: 3) it crashes.  Here is the message I have:

```
Error: src/app/app.component.html:28:10 - error TS2322: Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

28         [postLoveIts]="post.loveIts"
            ~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
    5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
```

Here is my code:

app.component

```
> import { Component } from '@angular/core';
> 
> 
> @Component({   selector: 'app-root',   templateUrl:
> './app.component.html',   styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'] })  
> export class AppComponent {
>     posts = [
>     {
>         title: "First Post",  
>         content: "StringString1String1String1String1",  
>         loveIts: "3",  
>         created: new Date()
>     },
>     { 
>       title: "Second post",  
>       content: "String2String2String2String2",  
>       loveIts: "6",  
>       created: new Date()
>     },
>     {  
>       title: "Third Post",  
>       content: "String3String3String3String3String3",  
>       loveIts: "18",  
>       created: new Date()
>     },   ];
```

post-list.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-post-list',
  templateUrl: './post-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./post-list.component.scss']
})
export class PostListComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() postTitle = 'string';
  @Input() postContent = 'string';
  ***@Input() postLoveIts = 'number';***
  @Input() postCreated = new Date;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  addOne() {
    let postLoveIts = this.postLoveIts ;

  }
}
```

I can't juste declare it as a number like @Input() postLoveIts = number even for the string, and it seems in app.component I can't declare it like that loveIts: 18 (for example), vs code give me this error : "message": "'number' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here."

here is my app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <h2>Mes posts</h2>
      <ul class="list-group">
        <app-post-list *ngFor="let post of posts"
        [postTitle]="post.title"
        [postContent]="post.content"
        [postLoveIts]="post.loveIts"
        [postCreated]="post.created"
        ></app-post-list>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for your help... I hope i'm clear... I just have string and no number to resume...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving types to your input properties, you have initialized them. Change you input properties to this:

```
@Input() postTitle : string;
@Input() postContent: string;
@Input() postLoveIts: number;
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of the `@Input` decorator is

```
bindingPropertyName: <TYPE>
```

Example from your code -

```
@Input() postLoveIts: number
```

Answer (score 0):

besides what @Ritesh already said, when you declare your posts array you initialize your 'loveIts' property with a string. Try making it a number also.

```
posts = [
    {
        ...
        loveIts: 3, // instead of loveIts: '3'
        created: new Date()
}...]
```

I strongly suggest you add a linter to your project to help a bit with the learning curve.

Check out this for typescript:
https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint